# Adding wallet system to magento2 customers

Tags: customer, magento2.2, payment-gateway, sales

I want to create a custom wallet for the magento store customers. I am not able to get any tutorials regarding this. Can anyone pls help me in creating a wallet for my store.

Comment: You can purchase third party extension.

Comment: I cant find any free extensions. Only paid are available.

Comment: There are not any free extension available. You can purchase paid or you need to develop a custom module.

Comment: No. There is not any tutorials for wallet. You can find out way for how to develop a custom module.